# How to pass the current element to a function from html file

Tags: javascript, function, this

I'm trying to reuse a function for different elements, is there a way that I can use my code for different input elements onchange. Passing this as keyword or keeping parameters empty isn't helping out

```js
function checksize() {
  if (this.files[0].size > 2097152) {
    alert("File is too big!");
    this.value = "";
    this.className = "is-invalid form-control-file";
  } else {
    this.className = "form-control-file"
  };
}
```

```html
<input onchange="checksize(this)" required accept=".jpg, .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .png" id="idfile" class="form-control-file" type="file" name="idfile">
```

Comment: That's correct, but you are passing the context as parameter, so you won't find it in the `this` of the function. Add a parameter to the function (like `checksize(el)`), it will be fulfilled with the element reference

Comment: Ps. Check other examples and documentation before asking a question, it would have saved a lot of time to we both :)

Comment: And then change `this` to `el` in your `checksize()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `bind` `this` with `call` or `apply`:

```
<input onchange="checksize.call(this)" required  accept=".jpg, .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, png" id="idfile" class="form-control-file" type="file" name="idfile">
```

Comment: Instructions inside html are evaluated, not called. So you need to use `call` or `apply`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `this`. This is probably the simplest way.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input[type='file']").forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener("click", function() {
    checksize.call(input);
  });
});

function checksize() {
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

```html
<input id="idfile1" type="file">
<input id="idfile2" type="file">
<input id="idfile3" type="file">
```

If you are willing to use jQuery you can do this:

```js
$("input[type='file']").on("click", checksize);

function checksize() {
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="idfile1" type="file">
<input id="idfile2" type="file">
<input id="idfile3" type="file">
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the passed argument in the function:

```js
function checksize(that) {
  if (that.files[0].size > 2097152) {
    alert("File is too big!");
    that.value = "";
    that.className = "is-invalid form-control-file";
  } else {
    that.className = "form-control-file"
  };
}
```

```html
<input onchange="checksize(this)" required accept=".jpg, .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .png" id="idfile" class="form-control-file" type="file" name="idfile">
```

Or, instead of defining the event in the HTML, you can append it dynamically, using:

```
document.getElementById('idfile').addEventListener('change', checksize);
```

and use your function (using the `this` keyword):

```js
document.getElementById('idfile').addEventListener('change', checksize);

function checksize() {
  if (this.files[0].size > 2097152) {
    alert("File is too big!");
    this.value = "";
    this.className = "is-invalid form-control-file";
  } else {
    this.className = "form-control-file"
  };
}
```

```html
<input required accept=".jpg, .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .png" id="idfile" class="form-control-file" type="file" name="idfile">
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function checksize(event){
    // use event to read ll files and read and write the element properties
    if(this.files[0].size > 2097152){
    alert("File is too big!");
    this.value = "";
    this.className = "is-invalid form-control-file";
    }else{
        this.className = "form-control-file"
    };
}
```

Comment: I see you added an `event` parameter, but never used it in the function.